# how to install Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.6.3-arm

Tags: qt, cross-platform

To execute the Qt executable in ARM board i need Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.6.3-arm , but I don't find any site to download and install Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.6.3-arm. Anybody having idea of how to do it please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angstrom cross compiler is better option when compared to Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.6.3-arm because the Angstrom cross compiler works fine in arm based boards.